# Apply Effect on multiple elements in sequence

Tags: apache-flex, move, effect, sequential

I'm trying to apply a Move-Effect on multiple elements. They are moving all together but I prefer it in seqeunce.

```
<s:Move id="thumbMover" target="{thumb}"/>

private function addItemThumbs ( ) : void {
    for each ( var item : ItemVO in _items ) {
        thumb = new Thumb;
        thumb._item = item;
        thumbMover.createInstance(thumb);
        thumbMover.xFrom = stage.width;
        thumbMover.yFrom = stage.height;
        thumbMover.xTo = xValue;
        thumbMover.yTo = yValue;
        thumbMover.play();
        addElement(thumb);
        xValue = xValue + item.itemTnW + Config.getInstance().vBorderItm;
        if ( xValue >= stage.width - item.itemTnW - 200 ) {
            xValue = Config.getInstance().xValueItm;
            yValue = yValue + item.itemTnH + Config.getInstance().hBorderItm;
        }
    }   
}
```

Thanks for taking time!

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Use a sequence.  More info here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fab.html

Something like

```
<s:Sequence>
   <s:Move />
   <s:Move />
</s:Sequence>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't check it. Do I need for each element a single effect?